# How to include daylight hour change in a query so it gives 25 hours, or 23 in a day instead of 24

Tags: laravel, eloquent, timezone, timescaledb

In DB ( Postgres / TimescaleDB ), I have a measure each 30min. So, it means in a normal day, I have 48 measures. Timestamp is stored with type "timestamp without timezone"

Now, for the 2 special days where we change CDT in France ( `2020-10-25` and `2021-03-28` ), I should have respectively have 50 and 46 measures.

But when I query :

```
    $measuresByTS = Measure::where('time', '>=', $from)
        ->where('time', '<=', $to)
        ->...
```

I always get 48 measures which is logical, but not what I want.

How should I get the 46 or the 50 measures on thoses 2 days ? Is there any TimescaleDB function that manages that ?

Here is what I should get:

when 46 measures:

I should have measures from `2021-03-28T23:00:00Z` to `2021-03-28T21:30:00Z` (formatted in french TZ)

when 50 measures:

I should have measures from `2021-03-28T22:00:00Z` to from `2021-03-28T22:30:00Z`(formatted in french TZ)

How should I do it ???

Comment: Maybe this related question can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383108/time-zone-with-daylight-savings-times-in-postgresql